# How do I deploy a solution with multiple projects

Tags: vb.net

I have a solution on VS2012 that has 2 projects, they were combined. I now need to deploy the solution, but when I deploy only the primary project deploys. The project that was added does not deploy.

The main project is a Windows Form project, the added project is a VSTO, in case this makes a difference.

I searched for help on the subject, but I only found deployment on one project.  I am looking for any resources on how to deploy a solution with multiple projects as one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click your deployment project, select 'Add' then 'project output'